# Hibernate making N+1 queries to init lazy collection in superclass

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I'm trying to whip some badly configured and very old Hibernate mapping into shape.
It's still using hbm.xml to configure so I hope you can read it, but at least we are using a fairly recent Hibernate version, 5.2.12.

This is cut down from the original to show the essential features. The base class RepoResource has a bidirectional one-to-many collection of RepoAccessEvent which we make extra-lazy. The subclass RepoFileResource has a "data" property which we make extra-lazy because it's a blob.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class abstract="true" 
            table="Resource" 
            name="com.example.RepoResource" batch-size="1000">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <natural-id mutable="true">
            <property name="name" not-null="true" length="200" type="string" column="name"/>
            <many-to-one column="parent_folder" name="parent" outer-join="auto"/>
        </natural-id>
        <set inverse="true" cascade="save-update" name="accessEvents" outer-join="auto" batch-size="1000" lazy="extra">
            <key column="resource_id"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.example.RepoAccessEvent"/>
        </set>
    </class>
  <class table="AccessEvent" name="com.example.RepoAccessEvent" batch-size="1000">
    <id name="id" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="eventDate" column="event_date" type="timestamp" not-null="true" index="access_date_index"/>
    <many-to-one name="resource" 
                 column="resource_id" class="com.example.RepoResource"
                 not-null="true"
                 index="access_res_index"/>
  </class>

    <joined-subclass 
            name="com.example.RepoFileResource"
            extends="com.example.RepoResource"
            table="FileResource" batch-size="1000">
        <key column="id"/>
        <property name="data" type="blob" length="20971520" column="data" lazy="true"/>
        <property name="fileType" length="20" type="string" column="file_type"/>
        <many-to-one column="reference" name="reference" class="com.example.RepoFileResource" />
    </joined-subclass>
<hibernate-mapping>
```

I notice that when we do a list() on a criteria and we load a bunch of the RepoFileResources, there's a query like this for each resource:

```
select count(id) from AccessEvent where resource_id = ?
```

I have been doing some profiling to discover where these queries are getting run, and the stack goes through some generated methods (it appears that we are using Javassist):

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery() DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96  <2 recursive calls>
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(PreparedStatement) ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60
org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.getSize(Serializable, SharedSessionContractImplementor) AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1943
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork() AbstractPersistentCollection.java:157
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork() AbstractPersistentCollection.java:146
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection$LazyInitializationWork) AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize() AbstractPersistentCollection.java:145
!! org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size() PersistentSet.java:143
!! com.example.RepoFileResource.$$_hibernate_clearDirtyCollectionNames() RepoFileResource.java
!! com.example.RepoFileResource.$$_hibernate_clearDirtyAttributes() RepoFileResource.java
!! org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.afterInitialize(Object, SharedSessionContractImplementor) PojoEntityTuplizer.java:297
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.afterInitialize(Object, SharedSessionContractImplementor) AbstractEntityPersister.java:4635
org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(Object, EntityEntry, boolean, SharedSessionContractImplementor, PreLoadEvent) TwoPhaseLoad.java:278
org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(Object, boolean, SharedSessionContractImplementor, PreLoadEvent) TwoPhaseLoad.java:125
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(PreLoadEvent, ResultSetProcessingContextImpl, List) AbstractRowReader.java:238
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(ResultSetProcessingContextImpl, List) AbstractRowReader.java:209
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSet, SharedSessionContractImplementor, QueryParameters, NamedParameterContext, boolean, boolean, ResultTransformer, List) ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(SharedSessionContractImplementor, QueryParameters, LoadQueryDetails, boolean, ResultTransformer, List) AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(SharedSessionContractImplementor, QueryParameters, LoadQueryDetails, boolean, ResultTransformer) AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86
org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(Serializable, Object, SharedSessionContractImplementor, LockOptions) AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167
org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.LegacyBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder$LegacyBatchingEntityLoader.load(Serializable, Object, SharedSessionContractImplementor, LockOptions) LegacyBatchingEntityLoaderBuilder.java:124
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(Serializable, Object, LockOptions, SharedSessionContractImplementor) AbstractEntityPersister.java:4083
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(LoadEvent, EntityPersister) DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(EntityPersister, LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) SessionImpl.java:1239
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl, LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) SessionImpl.java:203
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(Serializable) SessionImpl.java:2804
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(Serializable) SessionImpl.java:2778
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$NaturalIdLoadAccessImpl.load() SessionImpl.java:3105
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(Criteria) SessionImpl.java:1865
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list() CriteriaImpl.java:370
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$35.doInHibernate(Session) HibernateTemplate.java:1051
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$35.doInHibernate(Session) HibernateTemplate.java:1040
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateCallback, boolean) HibernateTemplate.java:361
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateCallback) HibernateTemplate.java:328
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria, int, int) HibernateTemplate.java:1040
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria) HibernateTemplate.java:1032
```

Note the lines starting with "!!"; the PojoEntityTuplizer is calling two generated methods including `$$_hibernate_clearDirtyCollectionNames()` which then makes a PersistentSet.size() call that runs the count query.

I took a look at the code which does the bytecode generation, and apparently it wants to know the count of the accessEvents collection for *every single instance* leading to the N + 1 problem. This seems insane. I have a lot of other persistent types which I'm not showing, but only this type generates the count queries, and the only difference I can think of is that it has the lazy attribute which triggers the bytecode generation.

Is there any way to stop the count queries from happening?

Comment: Are you sure this is java? (This is clearly a program designed for making web applications) I don't remotely recognize this language.

Comment: @FailingCoder Hibernate is a Java library for object-relational mapping. The XML in the question is the config file that defines the mapping.

Comment: @dnault, you're correct. Originally Hibernate was only configurable with XML. This was prior to Java 5 which introduced annotations, which is back when Java developers were riding on dinosaurs (lol). But the XML has almost a 1-1 mapping to annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...after thinking about it, even if I could fix this with config or something, maybe the choice of association (bidirectional one-to-many) is just inappropriate. This kind of association would be used more typically in a composition, when there are just a few child objects and you usually want to fetch them along with the parent using a fetch join IIRC. But these access events are numerous and rarely used, and frankly a big headache. I'm thinking of just making it unidirectional many-to-one, from AccessEvent to Resource.